# Configure raspberry pi wifi by writing to micro SD card

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a raspberry pi but no external keyboard, mouse or ethernet cable to set it up - but I do have micro-sd card reader. Is there a way for me to just write my wireless internet config straight to the micro-sd card so the raspberry pi will be able to connect to the wifi, and then allow me to ssh in?

The micro-sd card already has Raspbian installed on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.

- Put the card in a drive and mount it.
- Go to the partition called `boot`.

Create an empty file called `ssh` just using:

```
touch ssh            # Works in Linux/macOS
type NUL >> ssh      # Works in Windows
```

Create a file called `wpa_supplicant.conf` with your WiFi settings - be very sure that Windows hasn't added any `.txt` extension:

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="NETWORK-NAME"
    psk="NETWORK-PASSWORD"
}
```

Once it works, and you can `ssh` successfully into the Raspberry Pi, be sure to run:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and permanently enable `ssh` for subsequent reboots.

Comment: I unpacked the `boot.tar.xz` in the SD card, should I just add the `ssh` and `wpa_supplicat.conf` files there then recompress it? There's a bunch of binaries in there, including the kernel image etc - is that the correct place?

Comment: Oh, I guess you have never started the Raspbian image in your Raspberry Pi then if you don't have a `boot` partition. I have never tried that, but I guess it should work - worst case you'll have to write the Raspbian image to the SD card again.

Comment: You may have to either wait quite a while as the Raspberry Pi boots the first time and extracts itself, or you may have to then boot again for it to work correctly on the second boot. You may have to look in your router's *DHCP Clients* table to see what address it allocated the RPi.